# Why I don't need to create a SparkSession in Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

Why I don't need to create a SparkSession in Databricks? Is a SparkSession created automatically when the cluster is set? Or somebody else did it for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is done only in the notebooks, to simplify user's work & avoiding them to specify different parameters, many of them won't have any effect because Spark is already started.  This behavior is similar to what you get when you start `spark-shell` or `pyspark` - both of them initialize the `SparkSession` and `SparkContext`:

```
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1635579272032).
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

But if you're running code from jar or Python wheel as job, then it's your responsibility to create corresponding objects.

Comment: So, can I say, when a cluster is set up and running, SparkSession is created in the back end of a notebook?

Comment: Yes. Everything is done to make user start working as fast as possible

Comment: where could we find the documentation? @AlexOtt for the databricks notebook part.

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-isolation.html#spark-session-isolation

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks environment, Whereas in Spark 2.0 the same effects can be achieved through SparkSession, without expliciting creating SparkConf, SparkContext or SQLContext, as they’re encapsulated within the SparkSession. Using a builder design pattern, it instantiates a SparkSession object if one does not already exist, along with its associated underlying contexts.ref: [link](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html)