# In Databricks, where does `spark.*` come from?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

When working in Azure Databricks, the `spark.sql()` function is available at startup; no imports necessary. But where does it come from?

`spark.sql`'s docs say it's from `pyspark.sql.session`:

```py
help(spark.sql)
```

```
Help on method sql in module pyspark.sql.session:
```

But when I try calling `sql()` from `pyspark.sql.session`, it fails:

```py
import pyspark.sql.session as spark

spark.sql
```

```
AttributeError: module 'pyspark.sql.session' has no attribute 'sql'
```

I'm developing a Python package to be used in Databricks, but I can't test it on my local machine without `spark`, but the `spark` scope doesn't seem to come from any package I can install locally with Poetry.

Comment: It says "help on **method** sql", so I assume `spark` itself is some kind of object from the module there. You should print `repr(spark)` to see if it will give you info about where it comes from. Also maybe `type(spark)` if my guess about being an object of a class is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spark` object is automatically initialized in the Databricks notebooks - it's just an instance of the `pyspark.sql.SparkSession` class - this covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774609/why-i-dont-need-to-create-a-sparksession-in-databricks).

In nutshell, it's analogous to explicit code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

and then use `spark.sql("....")`